# How to send several files via POST using cUrl

Tags: post, curl, multipartform-data

I use `python requests` to send `multipart POST`:

```
files = {"file1": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file1.xml", 'r'),
         "file2": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file2.crt", 'r'),
         "file3": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file3.pem", 'rb'),
         "file4": open("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file4.elf", 'rb')}
url = "http://some_url.com"
r = requests.post(url, data={"targetName": "Qwerty"}, files=files)
```

I want to rewrite it using `cURL`. There's a lot of information about how to do this, but none of found approaches seem to work. For now I have something like:

```
curl -F 'targetName=Qwerty' -F 'file1=@\"C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file1.xml\"' -F 'file2=@\"C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file2.crt\"' -F 'file3=@\"C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file3.pem\"' -F 'file4=@\"C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file4.elf\"' http://some_url.com
```

but this returns

```
400 Bad Request
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Required MultipartFile parameter 'file1' is not present</body></html>* Closing connection 0
```

What is wrong with my request? Do I need to specify headers?

Comment: Shouldn't double quotes be used on windows, rather than single quotes? Also with the double around the keypair, I don't think you need them around the path anymore

Comment: add `--trace-ascii dump.txt` to your curl command line and you'll get a full trace of what exactly curl sends. Verify that it looks like you meant it. Then verify that your server-side acts correctly.

Comment: @DanielStenberg, Thanks for your advice. I see that for first file `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="file1.xml" Content-Type: text/xml` request payload expected, but server get `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1" C:/Users/Path/to/file1.xml` instead. How should I modify my request?

Comment: That looks like there's some problem with the shell/quoting or something.